# Switching between proxies with Selenium IDE

Tags: proxy, selenium-ide

Is it possible to switch to another proxy during a test case in Selenium IDE? 
I know it's possible with Webdriver, but I am interested in Selenium IDE.

In Chrome I can add an extensions like FoxyProxy, then I can access the options of the FoxyProxy by going to a URL. However, in Firefox, I cannot reach the options of FoxyProxy via URL.

I see two options:

1. To find an extension for Firefox that will allow me to access the options of it via a URL. Does anyone know of one? Tried a lot already..
2. Some command in Selenium IDE that will allow me to click on the extension.
3. Do it by running some script.
4. Any other awesome idea.

Thanks!